# How to use a variable to name another variable

Tags: python

if I have a list such as

```
availableQuestions = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5"]
```

and I want to have a for loop using it such as

```
for x in availableQuestions:
    newButton = button((22, 19, 170), xC, yC, 180, 100, f"{pV}")
    newButton.draw(screen, (0, 0, 0))
```

but I want to have the name of the newButton to also have the name of x connected with it for example newButtona1, newButtona2.
I need this so that I can later address each of these buttons independently.

Comment: `newButton` is a string?

Comment: newButton is the name of the variable where the button is being stored at, but because Im in a for loop, I need to have a way to differentiate each one, so I need to have to name of the item in the list in the name.

Comment: "use a variable to name another variable" **don't do this**. Use a *container* like a list or a dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary like this

```
buttons = dict()
for x in availableQuestions:
    buttons[x]= button((22, 19, 170), xC, yC, 180, 100, f"{pV}")
    buttons[x].draw(screen, (0, 0, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know if I will be able to call these buttons as variables later, like when checking if they were clicked?

Comment: yeah you can go through the dictionary using a for loop and conditionally check each button

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dictionary and use the available question identifiers as part of a string key for storing the button itself.

Example:

```
available_questions = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5"]

aq_buttons = {}

for key in available_questions:
    button_name = "button_" + key
    aq_buttons[button_name] = button((22, 19, 170), xC, yC, 180, 100, f"{pV}")
    aq_buttons[button_name].draw(screen, (0, 0, 0))
```